# Declaring an array of linked list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list

I got the compile error message "Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)" when I tried to declare an array of linked lists.

```
public LinkedList<LevelNode>[2] ExistingXMLList;
```

Also, if I wanted to create a small array of strings, isn't the following the correct way?

```
string [2] inputdata;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declare an array with just [].

```
LinkedList[] XMLList;
```

Then you instantiate it with the size.

```
XMLList = new LinkedList[2];
```

Or both at the same time:

```
LinkedList[] XMLList = new LinkedList[2];
```

To add LinkedLists to this array you type:

```
XMLList[0] = new LinkedList();
XMLList[1] = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  I never use arrays.

Comment: No need to apologize, Visual Studio spoils us all!

Comment: What if you are using an array of a class where the constructor seems to require a paramenter?

If you use new like this:

XmlTextReader[] r;

r = new XmlTextReader [2];

Then how would you pass the filename to r[0] and r[1] ?

Comment: This code is instantiating an Array.  If you want to add values to that array you have to do XMLList[0] = new XMLList();

Comment: I am not able to use in a .NET Core 3.1 console app. Did this change?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
LinkedList[] ExistingXMLList = new LinkedList[2];
```

Comment: I thought I was crazy, but then I decided that even with 15.5k rep he could still make a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

---

You can try this
 LinkedList<>[] adjacentList = new LinkedList<>[2];
using the generic type linked list requires 1 type parameter